# Examples of bounded function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(a,b)$?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

What are some examples of functions taking values from $(-\infty, \infty)$ to an open interval $(a,b)$? I'm trying to write a single index model that possesses this property, and the most popular example I can think of is $\frac{\exp(X\beta)}{1+\exp(X\beta)}$ of which values are in $(0,1)$. I can modify it to take values between $(a,b)$ but just wonder about more creative ideas...

Edit: It would be great that the function is as smooth as possible, twice differentiable is ideal! and monotone. Bijection is a plus, but it must be hard.

Comment: Bijectively, or not?

Comment: constant map? $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: $\arctan(x): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow (-\tfrac{\pi}{2},\tfrac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: what properties do you want it to satisfy? does it have to be surjective? smooth?

Comment: @yanko You probably mean surjective?

Comment: yeh sorry......

Comment: $tanh(x)$ also works.